# AngularJS implementing ui-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, angular-grid

I am attempting to use the ui-grid along w/ AngularJS for the first time. I was initially doing a tutorial on ngGrid... but when I looked up the reference files they all said ui-grid on them.... so now I am a bit confused.

I have referenced the following in my aspx page:-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<link href="Content/ui-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

My Javascript to get the GridView to work looks like this:-

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="secondaryContent">
<script type="text/javascript">    
        var app = angular.module('', ['ngGrid']);
        app.controller('UserController', function ($scope) {

            $scope.myData = [{ name: "xxxx", age: 50 },
                             { name: "yyyy", age: 43 },
                             { name: "zzzz", age: 27 },
                             { name: "eeee", age: 29 },
                             { name: "ffff", age: 34 }];

            $scope.gridOptions = {
                data: 'myData',
                showGroupPanel: true,
                jqueryUIDraggable: true
            };
        });

  </script>
</asp:Content>
```

and finally my aspx body looks like:-

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


    <h1>My AngularJS Application</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div style="margin-top: 40px"></div>
        <div data-ng-app="" data-ng-controller="UserController">
            <b>Employee List</b><br />
            <br />
            <div class="gridStyle" data-ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

With all of this in place, I get an empty grid with the following style, referenced through my div class:-

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px
}
```

I must be missing something ... no idea what though.

When I check the console on my browser, it gives me the following error:- **Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $rootScopeProvider <- $rootScope**

**Edit:-** 
I created my code in plunker and it works on the emulator but not via my Visual Studio 2013 on the aspx page (it works via an html page):-

http://plnkr.co/edit/L3n5CETMtlTQagNm6axK?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must inject `'ui.grid'` not `'ngGrid'` and change implementation:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

Check this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bq8AVBVb7UxwBeBNKoRO?p=preview

Comment: It says - ui-grid is an unknown attribute... I even copied all your references from pnkr...

Comment: I think you must update you file : ui-grid.min.js from : https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js

Comment: so I created my code on plunker and it works.. but not via my visual studio 2013.... same code.. same referencess. http://plnkr.co/edit/L3n5CETMtlTQagNm6axK?p=preview

Comment: deleted all files... recreated everything and it worked. but thank you for your example. It helped me solidify some of my doubts.

Comment: Why does this process work on an html page but not on an aspx page?

Comment: so I finally got it to work... I had multiple references in my script tag and some of them were bad/older version...hence causing the issue... the html page worked because it had only the good references...:) Thanks for all your help.